# FOSFacebookBundle works, but FOSUserBundle does not seem to work

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle

I can login with FOSFacebookBundle and everything works. But, FOSUserBundle does not seem to work because profiler shows Username: anon and Roles: {}. And, there is no user data about logged in user in database. Maybe, I didn't understand how it works. Please, help.

This is my config.yml

```
fos_user:
 db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
 firewall_name: public
 user_class: Trade\TradeBundle\Entity\User

fos_facebook:
  file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
  alias:  facebook
  app_id: my_app_id
  secret: app_secret_key
  cookie: true
  permissions: [user_about_me]

services:
 fos_facebook.auth:
    class: Trade\TradeBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
    arguments:
        facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
        userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
        validator: "@validator"
        container: "@service_container"
```

This is my security.yml

```
security:
factories:
    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_FACEBOOK
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    my_fos_facebook:
        id: fos_facebook.auth

firewalls:
    public:
        pattern:   ^/.*
        fos_facebook:
            app_url: "app_url"
            server_url: "server_url"
            login_path: /user/login
            check_path: /user/login_check
            default_target_path: /
            provider: my_fos_facebook
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
```

The code below does not seem to work because when I log in with facebook setTimeout(goLogIn, 500) function inside if is not called.

```
function goLogIn(){
    window.location.href = "{{ path('user_login_check') }}";
}

function onFbInit() {
    if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
            if (response.session || response.authResponse) {
                setTimeout(goLogIn, 500);
            } else {
                window.location.href = "{{ path('_security_logout') }}";
            }
       });
    }
}
```

These are my controller actions:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/login", name = "user_login")
 */
public function loginAction()
{

}

/**
 * @Route("/user/login_check", name = "user_login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for FOSUserBundle to work together with FOSFacebookBundle, you need to specify a specific login route just for the facebook login at `security.yml`:

```
  public:
    fos_facebook:
        check_path: /loginFacebook
```

Of course you are going to need to point that route correctly at `routing.yml`:

```
_security_check:
pattern: /loginFacebook
```

Then you need to change the check URL on the facebook javascript:

```
function goLogIn(){
    window.location.href = "{{ path('_security_check') }}";
}
```

The last thing is to create the controller and the action for the new route (this is very important, otherwise it's not going to work) and leave it empty:

```
public function loginFacebookAction()
{
    return array();
}
```

Of course you are going to need to adapt this to your needs, like where I use the `DefaultController`, you, apperantly, use the `UserController`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I have done it already. Sorry for not showing it earlier. I have one controller and two actions for check_path and login_path. I added them.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are storing empty data because of your permissions request:

```
permissions: [user_about_me]
```

I suggest changing to the tutorial recommended:

```
permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location]
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply. I changed permissions as you said. But, nothing changed.